# Is it possible to combine HLOOKUP with AVERAGE to get the average of a column if the title matches?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a very wide data set from which I need to average certain columns on a different sheet. So I want to list the column headers that I want to average, and then put a formula in that will HLOOKUP that column and then put in the average of it.

I can't use a static forumla like AVERAGE(TZ2:TZ800) because there are several big datasets that I'll have to do this on and the variables aren't always in the same columns.

Is this possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can adapt this solution to meet your actual set-up.

Assuming that the data you wish to average is in Sheet1 A2:J10, with the headers for that data in A1:J1, and that you enter the e.g. three headers of the columns for which you wish to perform the average in Sheet2 A1:C1, this **array formula**** will give you the desired average:

=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet1!A1:J1,Sheet2!A1:C1,0)),Sheet1!A2:J10))

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*